# "relation does not exist" in pg_table_size

Tags: postgresql

I get

> ERROR:  relation "testdb" does not exist

(note table name case!) from

```
SELECT pg_table_size('testDB');
```

(note table name case again!) despite

```
test=> \d
         List of relations
 Schema |   Name    | Type  | Owner 
--------+-----------+-------+-------
 public | testDB    | table | test
```

Is this a bug? 
Are mixed case table names illegal?

Comment: Is that a database? I mean by the name it should, right? If it's a database you should use `pg_database_size` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must quote the name

```
create table "testDB" (/* ... */);

SELECT pg_table_size('"testDB"');
```

Look at: http://rextester.com/ZEF73948