# How to make psycopg2 emit nested quotes?

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2

As per ["relation does not exist" in pg_table_size](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52670128/850781), I need to emit nested single *and* double quotes:

```
import psycopg2  as pg
from psycopg2 import sql

conn = pg.connect("dbname=test user=test")
table_name = "testDB"
cu = conn.cursor()
cu.execute(sql.SQL("SELECT pg_table_size(%s)"), (table_name,))
```

emits `SELECT pg_table_size('testDB')` which raises

> psycopg2.ProgrammingError: relation "testdb" does not exist

while

```
cu.execute(sql.SQL("SELECT pg_table_size({t})").format(t=sql.Identifier(table_name)))
```

emits `SELECT pg_table_size("testDB")` which raises

> psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column "testDB" does not exist

Obviously,

```
cu.execute(sql.SQL("SELECT pg_table_size(%s)"),('"testDB"',))
```

works fine, but I want to find the "official" way to emit `SELECT pg_table_size('"testDB"')`.

Experimentally, the following works:

```
cu.execute(sql.SQL("SELECT pg_table_size(%s)"),
           (sql.Identifier(table_name).as_string(conn), ))
```

is this TRT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Postgres function [`quote_ident(string text):`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html)

```
cu.execute("SELECT pg_table_size(quote_ident(%s))", (table_name, ))
```

I think your last example is a good alternative for the above solution.

Comment: Your last piece of code contains explicit quotes and thus is probably in the category of `NEVER DO THIS` in the page you quote. Is `quote_ident` a better solution than my `Identifier(table_name).as_string`?

Comment: *Never do this, because...?*. I don't think it's a bad practice, though `as_string()` is undoubtedly more elegant. I cannot see any performance differences between the two approaches.

Comment: [because](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#the-problem-with-the-query-parameters) ;-)

Comment: The second piece of code is a dangerous and bad idea and you should remove it from here ASAP. Then take your time to understand why.