# How to make psycopg2 emit no quotes?

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2

I want to create a table from Pytnon:

```
import psycopg2  as pg
from psycopg2 import sql

conn = pg.connect("dbname=test user=test")
table_name = "testDB"
column_name = "mykey"
column_type = "bigint"
cu = conn.cursor()
cu.execute(sql.SQL("CREATE TABLE {t} ({c} {y})").format(
    t=sql.Identifier(table_name),
    c=sql.Identifier(column_name),
    y=sql.Literal(column_type)))
```

Alas, this emits `CREATE TABLE "testDB" ("mykey" 'bigint')` which fails with a

> psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "'bigint'"

Of course, I can do something like

```
cu.execute(sql.SQL("CREATE TABLE {t} ({c} %s)" % (column_name)).format(
    t=sql.Identifier(table_name),
    c=sql.Identifier(column_name)))
```

but I suspect there is a more elegant (and secure!) solution.

PS. See also [How to make psycopg2 emit nested quotes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52670840/850781)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an example in [the documentation](http://psycopg.org/docs/sql.html#psycopg2.sql.SQL.format) how to build a query text with a placeholder. Use [`psycopg2.extensions.AsIs(object)`](http://psycopg.org/docs/extensions.html#psycopg2.extensions.AsIs) for `column_type`:

```
query = sql.SQL("CREATE TABLE {t} ({c} %s)").format(
    t=sql.Identifier(table_name),
    c=sql.Identifier(column_name)).as_string(cu)
    
cu.execute(query, [AsIs(column_type)])
```